# CSS circles shaking on animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have drawn a circle in CSS. I tried playing around with the code to fix this issue but to no avail. I have 2 main issues :

1. In Chrome : 
   The circles shake while rotating
2. In Firefox : 
   There appears a tail-like dot when the circle is animating in circular motions.

This is the CSS styling I am using :

```css
.followers_arc_outer{
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border-radius:100%;
    border:2px solid;
}
.followers_arc_start {
    border-color:transparent #ecd201 #ecd201 #ecd201;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.followers_arc_inner{
    position:absolute;
    top:18px;
    left: 18px;
    width: 280px;
    height:280px;
    border-radius:100%;
    border:2px solid;
    border-color:transparent #ecd201 #ecd201 #ecd201;
}
.o_circle {
    -webkit-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
    animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotation{
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {-webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);transform: rotate(359deg);}
}@keyframes rotation{
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {-webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);transform: rotate(359deg);}
}
.i_circle {
    -webkit-animation: rotation2 2s infinite linear;
   animation: rotation2 2s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotation2 {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);transform: rotate(359deg);}
    to   {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);transform: rotate(0deg);}
}@keyframes rotation2 {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);transform: rotate(359deg);}
    to   {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);transform: rotate(0deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="followers_arc_outer followers_arc_start o_circle"></div>
        <div class="followers_arc_inner followers_arc_start i_circle"></div>
```

I have created a fiddle. Here is the link : 
    http://jsfiddle.net/r8cqet2c/4/

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: i have a suspicion this might have something to do with hardware acceleration. you might be benefitted by reading this brief article: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css

Comment: Looks great in Firefox for me.

Comment: It's interesting, in Chrome it doesn't appear to be a perfect circle.

Comment: It is a common bug within Chrome theres tonnes of articles on Google with the same problem.

Comment: i don't see a problem - it's probably a conflict with your other code

Answer (score 3):

If your circles are big then the browsers may take time to render them. And at the same time when you try to rotate and animate them, then it would be hard for the browser to do that smoothly with the CPU graphics(which the browser uses by default).

But you can make use of your GPU in your browser by using some hardware accelerated CSS. Which will boost the performance of you animations. Here is the code you can apply to your circles to make them run smoother.

```
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

or you can use this below one...both will work..

```
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
   -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
   -o-transform: translateZ(0);
   transform: translateZ(0);
```

If you still see some weird lag or something in chrome or safari then you will have to add this below code as well.

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;

-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-moz-perspective: 1000;
-ms-perspective: 1000;
perspective: 1000;
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: The last part with perspective fixed my issue, thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe transform-origin and perspective-origin properties can help you:

- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_perspective-origin.asp

Comment: W3Schools is not a very reliable source.  There's MDN for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with anti-aliasing and rounding. I changed to background to plain black and made the animations stop after one round. When the circles are still you can see that the anti-aliasing makes some parts of the circles look less solid, especially when you zoom smaller. I don't see the shaking or the tail.

Answer (score 0):

**Any case is shaking**
I checked the code in Chrome, Mozilla, Opera and Safari (even 5.17 is working)

Maybe you're using a bad resolution or some graphic card problem.

Answer (score 0):

No problem here stand-alone. *(Chrome, Firefox, Safari)*

**If** you see a problem here stand-alone; it may be due to your **machine / hardware** or browser settings.

But it's likely some other code you have in your application **conflicting** with this code causing the shake.

Answer (score 0):

It's happens due to anti-aliasing and you can solve it by smoothing the border. You can use box-shadow with inset property instead of color with solid property in order to prevent it:

## CSS

```
.followers_arc_outer {
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border-radius:100%;
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 2px 0px #ecd201 inset;
}

.followers_arc_inner {
    position:absolute;
    top:18px;
    left: 18px;
    width: 280px;
    height:280px;
    border-radius:100%;
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 2px 0px #ecd201 inset;
}
```

heres the fiddle to see how it works :
http://jsfiddle.net/heartagramir/xdmuvu9s/

Answer (score 0):

To make transforms more smooth and prevent looking juddery or tattered you can reset translate3d to zero:

```
.transform {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-4.7deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-4.7deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: rotate(-4.7deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-4.7deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: rotate(-4.7deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

I would suggest to add translate3d(0, 0, 0) whenever you use transform